# unloading a dll in matlab

Tags: c#, matlab, dll, serial-port

I'm working with a .net DLL I've created previously as an interface between a serial device (programmable MCU) and MATLAB:
Example operation:
1. MATLAB sends a 'open port' request via the DLL to the serial port, 
2. The port is opened in the DLL and MATLAB have no control over the port (only the DLL has),
3. MATLAB sends additional requests (like read, write etc...) to the DLL and it responds accordingly 
4. MATLAB sends a 'close port' request via the DLL to the serial port, 
5. The port is closed BUT still occupied by the DLL.

The problem is that since the DLL is inside MATLAB and it cannot be unloaded (MATLAB, as stated in the MATHWORKS website, doesn't support unloading an already loaded .net DLL) and MATLAB cannot control the port directly, the port is unavailable until MATLAB is closed and the DLL is unloaded (happens only when MATLAB closes). This means that the user needs to close MATLAB a couple of times...

So, is their any work-around way to unload the DLL? or any another solution?

P.S, MATLAB has some serial capabilities but they are very limited in performance (data acquisition for example) hence they cannot be used (also, the DAQ-Toolbox is good but costs a-lot).

Comment: Maybe something could be done in your ClosePort() C# method? Can you post both Open and Close port C# functions? Is there something you do in Open that you don't do in Close?

Comment: Have you tried the command `clear mex`?

Answer (score 1):

*The port is closed BUT still occupied by the DLL* that is the actual problem, and it should be possible to fix: it is not likely at all that the .Net serial port api would not allow you to properly close a port. After all the System.IO.Ports.SerialPort class does have [Close method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.close%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which is supposed to completely close the port.

Anyway, possible solutions would include:

- expose COM in your assembly and using `actxserver` in matlab, it does have unload capabilities
- wrap your .Net lib in a dll exposing only pure C functions and use matlab's `loadlibrary`/`unloadlibrary`
- don't write in C# but use C and use it like above
- should the problem really be in the .Net serial port handling: don't use the .Net SerialPort but use `DllImport` to use the windows api functions that can deal with serial ports directly ([CreateFile](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32.CreateFile) etc); then again, that is probably what the .Net SerialPort class does internally as well...